# Coordinate Systems in Loop Integrals

Tags: quantum-field-theory, integration

Let us consider a two-point two-loop integral $\int \mathrm{d} ^ 4 k _ {2} \int \mathrm{d} ^ 4 k _ {1} \, f(k _ {1}, k _ {2}, p)$, where $k _ {1}$, $k _ {2}$ and $p$ are four-dimensional vectors in Euclidean space and $p$ and $-p$ are the external momenta. There are three angles present in $f$: the angle $x$ between $k _ {1}$ and $k _ {2}$, the angle $y$ between $p$ and $k _ {1}$ and the angle $z$ between $p$ and $k _ {2}$. Which coordinate system is most suitable for consistently performing the integrals?

For instance, for the one-loop integral $\int \mathrm{d} ^ 4 k \, f(k, p)$, I take $p$ to be the z-direction. Then $p = k \cos \omega$, where $\mathrm{d} V = |k| ^ {3} \, \sin ^ {2} \omega \, \sin \theta \, \mathrm{d} |k| \, \mathrm{d} \omega \, \mathrm{d} \theta \, \mathrm{d} \phi$ is the four-dimensional spherical volume element and $|k|$ is the Euclidean norm of $k$. Is there a two-loop analog coordinate system which takes into account the three aforementioned angles?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing Coordinate Systems in Two-Loop Integrals](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/111302/changing-coordinate-systems-in-two-loop-integrals)

Comment: I'm not so sure this is a duplicate. This one is asking what the best choice of coordinate system is, whereas the other question is asking whether it's allowed to make a particular change of coordinates.